# How to call codeigniter controller method from view

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, codeigniter

I know that in CI view if i put the

```
hostname/projectname/controllername/methodname
```

it will call the CI controller's method.

but this doesn't work. it says request url isn't existing. however, if i put like,

```
hostname/projectname/index.php/controllername/methodname
```

it works.
what is the problem?

Comment: You need `mod_rewrite` installed on the server and you need to edit your `.htaccess` as appropriate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure your .htaccess file to remove the index.php from being required.

If you don't already have an .htaccess file then [follow this guide](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-easily-create-and-edit-htaccess-file-for-your-site/).

In code igniter you will want the .htaccess file to look like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    ### Code Igniter Updates

    # If your default controller is something other than
    # "welcome" you should probably change this
    RewriteRule ^(welcome(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Enforce www
    # If you have subdomains, you can add them to 
    # the list using the "|" (OR) regex operator
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|subdomain) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Enforce NO www
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]

    ###

    # Removes access to the system folder by users.
    # Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    # previously this would not have been possible.
    # 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    # Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

Replacing: `www.domain.tld` with your domain, localhost for example during your testing.

Comment: still not working :(. Is it because i missed installing mod_rewrite?

Comment: mod_rewrite is part of apache server installs, so you may want to check if your local apache install has mod_rewrite enabled.

Comment: i checked with phpinfo() and i checked that it is inside loaded modules. Does that mean it is enable? if it is, why isn't it still not working :(

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your `htaccess file`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Refer https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

**Update Full Code**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
</IfModule>
```